# not getting a default value when setting up column with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My default value is not showing up when I set up my Table like this in SQLAlchemy:

```
Table(
    "my_log",
    metadata,
    Column("date", TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now()),
    Column("message", String(100)),
)
```

Whereas if I set it up directly in the postgres cli is works:

```
CREATE TABLE my_log(date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, message VARCHAR(100));
```

Comment: try `datetime.datetime.now` (without the brackets)

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, it still isn't working, i'm trying to set the default value in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: however, using server_default = func.now() instead of default is working

Comment: `default` is a SQLAlchemy side default value. Use `server_default` if you want to have an SQL side default value.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I'm just wondering why the `default` way is not working, but the `server_default` way is.

Comment: I've just run a test and it's generating the timestamp when an object is inserted. So what is not working for you?

Comment: @rfkortekaas I don't see the `Default` value in the psql cli (when I check `\d my_log;`).  It still shows nothing, when I use the parameters `default  = datetime.datetime.now`

Comment: That’s correct behavior. `default` is completely handled by SQLAlchemy. If you insert a new record via SQLAlchemy with only `message` you will see that the time stamp will be populated with the current time.

Comment: so if I insert with just postgresql there will be an error because the default value is nothing, but if I insert with SQLAlchemy it will handle it correctly because the default value is being handled with the SQLAlchemy side?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. So if you want to use both you need to use `server_default`